# What versions of Darwin's libacl have the acl_get_file bug?

Tags: acl, darwin

In some versions of Darwin's libacl, there's a bug in the `acl_get_file` function in which in spuriously returns null and sets `errno` to `ENOENT` when passed paths to valid files. There are a decent number of configure scripts out there which check for this (see [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2006-09/msg00323.html), for example), but all of them do it just by checking for the behavior. I was wondering if it's known what specific versions of libacl contain the bug, or if I just have to go testing a bunch in order to find out.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to *confirm* the absence of a bug is to test that the functionality works in the way that you expect it to function. But if you just want Apple's statement on the issue, go to https://developer.apple.com/ and register as an Apple Developer (it does not cost anything).

One registered, navigate to the bug reporting section of the site. You will encounter an error initially, as Apple's authentication system will tell you that before logging in to report a bug, you need to register as a developer. Ignore that error and click through to continue to the bug reporting site.

Sign in again, and you'll see the bug viewer interface. You probably won't have access to any bug reports, so generate a new one, reporting the bug about `acl_get_file` and wait for Apple's response.

It's the long way round, but in terms of getting confirmation that the bug has been fixed, there appears to be no other way.

Comment: Is there anywhere I could look besides Apple themselves? Since Darwin is (AFAIK) technically open-source, shouldn't there be some public place that a commit log or changelist is available?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2006-09/msg00323.html) for details related to acl.m4 (AC_FUNC_ACL): Disable ACL support altogether when we detect Darwin 8.7.0's acl_get_file bug.

Comment: So are you saying that anything after 8.7.0 is fine? Do you know if they fixed it right away?